# Adding Columns in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way to add all the marks under total Column?

This is my school project work.

The Question is to create a query and show ROll Number and Name and total marks 
obtained by each student using both the table while adding fields in query.

[image: see the image]

Comment: You could use a [calculated field](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html) for that. But you shouldn't. Calculations belong in queries, not in your table.

Comment: I have to calculate manually ? @ErikvonAsmuth

Comment: No, of course not. You calculate using a query, like June7's first function. Note that his/her comment on normalization is apt, if you'd normalize the table the calculation would've been easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is no intrinsic function to sum multiple fields. If your table structure were normalized could do a CROSSTAB query. Otherwise, build a simple SELECT query that constructs the Total field with an expression:
`[Bengali]+[English]+[Maths]+[Physics]+[Chemistry]`.

Be aware that if any field is Null the expression will return Null. If needed, deal with possible Null in each field: `Nz([Bengali],0)` or some recommend `Iif([Bengali] Is Null, 0, [Bengali])`.

There is no need to have Total field in table.  Calculate the value when needed. However, starting with Access2010 could use a Calculated type field in table. Some developers despise their use but they do work. They do have limitations, for instance the Nz() will not work nor will `Is Null`. `IIf(IsNull([Bengali]),0,[Bengali])`.

Comment: Been a while since I used 2007 and couldn't remember so I relied on MS KB info which said calculated type introduced with 2010. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-30AD644F-946C-442E-8BD2-BE067361987C